# bash - no such file or directory for ATOM text editor

Tags: linux, unix

I have installed the ATOM text editor the other day, and it works fine when I launch it within the installation directory. However, its tedious to go there every time, so I added it to my profile.

the command I added is:

```
 export PATH=$PATH:/home/cole/ATOM/atom-1.14.3/usr/bin
```

But when I try to open it from my home directory I get the error:

```
bash: ./atom: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to launch atom directly from terminal by typing in `atom` and pressing `enter`, I would suggest to create an alias for it instead.

Open up .bashrc file:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

(Or use some other text editor.)

Then scroll to the end of the file and add the following rows

```
# Alias for launching atom text editor
alias atom='/home/cole/ATOM/atom-1.14.3/usr/bin/atom'
```

Now terminal needs to be relaunched for the alias to work.

Hope this helps.